# Calling validation through ajax function

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, validation

I have two pieces of javascript that I would like to work together. I have a form that is submitted via ajax, and a form validation script, that I would like to work together to prevent the ajax form submission if the validation fails.

Here is the ajax form submission script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){$(".sendName").click(function(){
var jsuser=$("#jsuser").val();
var jemail=$("#jemail").val();
var jusid=$("#jusid").val();
$.post("recomend.php",{jsuser:jsuser,jusid:jusid,jemail:jemail},function(data){$("#loadName")
.html(data)
.effect('bounce', { times: 5, distance: 30 }, 300);
  });
 });
});
$('#start').click(function() {
  $('#effect').toggle('fast', function() {
   });
});
</script>
```

This code works perfectly, and the form is submitted.

I also have the validation code partially working. If incorrect information is entered the error message is shown beside the field, but the form can still be submitted.

On a normal form the validation code is called like this:

```
<form method="post" action="formprocess.php" name="form1" id="form1" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
```

So, I need to know how to do the equivalent of:

```
onsubmit="return validate(this)"
```

in the ajax submission code, and not submit the form if there are errors.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you not award upvotes to helpful answers provided by people assisting you with your problem?

Comment: I usually do. I also always accept the answer that best helps with my problem. When I was trying to sort this out earlier I was in a bit of a rush so just marked the accepted answer and left. However, I always check my questions for new posts and comments, and to accept an answer and mark up the answers that were even slightly helpful. Both answers on this question helped me figure out a few things, so they have both been voted up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just do the following?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){$(".sendName").click(function(){

var jsuser=$("#jsuser").val();
var jemail=$("#jemail").val();
var jusid=$("#jusid").val();
if(validate(jsuser, jemail, jusid)){
$.post("recomend.php",{jsuser:jsuser,jusid:jusid,jemail:jemail},function(data){$("#loadName")
.html(data)
.effect('bounce', { times: 5, distance: 30 }, 300);
  });
 });
});
$('#start').click(function() {
  $('#effect').toggle('fast', function() {
   });
});
}
</script>
```

Where `validate` does your validation

Comment: I ended up doing something very similar to this.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".sendName").click(function(){
  if (!validate(this.form)) return;
  // rest of your function, including AJAX call
});
```

*The `.form` property is available on all form elements (HTMLSelectElement, HTMLOptionElement, HTMLInputElement, HTMLTextAreaElement, HTMLButtonElement, HTMLLabelElement, HTMLFieldSetElement, HTMLLegendElement, HTMLObjectElement, and HTMLIsIndexElement).*

Comment: By [writing JavaScript](http://www.echoecho.com/javascript6.htm), e.g. `if (…){ … }else{ … }`

Comment: I'm familiar with if statements. Just not 100% sure about the "return" in your code. Would I do if (!validate(this.form)){ return;} else { } according to your posted code?

Comment: In your code, what is the "this" referencing? Is it referencing a form with the class ".sendName"? That is actually the class of the submit button that is used to send the form via ajax. If I was going to hard-code in a reference to the form what would I use in place of "this.form" in your code?

Comment: `this` is the element upon which the `click` handler was registered. As I noted in the question, elements of a form (like the submit button) have a `.form` property that references the form itself. Based on your original validation code, I was assuming that your `validate()` method takes as its argument the form that will be validated.

Comment: Thanks for the info on the .form property :)